# How do I apply a conditional formatting rule to an entire table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large table with lots of conditional format rules which colourise a row based on a column value. However, if I add rows when a filter is active, it breaks all the 'applies to' columns.

How can I apply a rule to all rows of a table, without further additions breaking the rules?

This is on Excel 15.28 for Mac, if that helps.

Comment: I have this issue for over 10 years, through all Excel versions. I spent a lot of time trying to fix it, I think there is no solution.

Comment: I tried a simple example here and adding rows to tables, filter active or not, does not break the rules for conditional formatting. It still works for all rows, including the ones I added. Can you provide some example, so we can work directly on it?